Burger menu pushing items to the bottom
My burger menu always makes some problems and when I try to include it into any page the items on the page get pushed to the bottom. I tried it fixing it with position absolute but it didn't really work out either. I just want my elements to be on the right side of the burger menu and also float left didn't really looked good either.
Here is my code of the burger menu in HTML

<body> 
<div id=alles>
    
<div class=schale> 
    <div class=burger>
    
        <div class=bar>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class=seitenbar>
     <form>
         <div class=buttoncontainer>
            <div class=buttonbox>
                <i class="fa-regular fa-house"></i>  <input class=buttons formaction=homepage.php type=submit value=Home>  
            </div>    
            <div class=buttonbox>
                <br> <i class="fa-regular fa-key"></i> <input class=buttons formaction=register.php type=submit value=Registrierung>
            </div>
            <div class=buttonbox>
                <br>  <i class="fa-regular fa-clipboard-user"></i>  <input class=buttons formaction=login.php type=submit value=Login>
            </div>
        </div>   
     </form>
    </div>
     
</div>
</body>

And the CSS code of the burger menu
*{
   margin: 0;
    
}
.buttoncontainer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 0.5vw;
    padding-right: 0.5vw;
}

.buttons{
    margin-top: 5vh;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
    height: auto;   
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 5%;
    transition: 0.3s;
   border-radius: 1vh;
}

.buttons:hover{
    transition: all 0.3s;
   color:cadetblue;
   background-color: #1c1c21;
}
.schale{
    
    position: relative;
    display:flex;   
    width: 10vw;
    min-height: 6vh;
    
    background-color: #1c1c21;
    z-index: 0;
}

.burger {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 2vh;
    width: auto;
    border-color: red;
    padding-top: 0.5vw;
    margin-top: 0.5vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;    
    /* transition:all .5s ease-in-out; */
    z-index: 0;
}

.bar{
    min-height: 0.5vh;
    min-width:1vw;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    border-radius: 5%;
    transition: all  0.5s ease-in-out;
    border-color: brown;
    z-index: 0;
}

.bar::before, .bar::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 0.5vh;
    min-width: 1vw;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    border-radius: 5%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.bar::before{
    transform: translateY(-1vh);
}

.bar::after{
    transform: translateY(1vh);
}

.burger.offen .bar{
    transform: translateX(-1.5vw);
    background-color:transparent;
    background-color:   transparent;
}

.burger.offen .bar::before{
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(1vw, -2vh);
}

.burger.offen .bar::after{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1vw, 2vh);
}

.seitenbar{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-content: center; 
    width:  10vw;
    left:   -21vw;
    height: 94.91vh;
    background-color: #1c1c21;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 2;
    
}

.fa-house{
 color:cadetblue;
}
.fa-key{
    color:cadetblue;
}

.fa-clipboard-user{
    
    color:cadetblue;
}



and the JavaScript part of the menu
const burgerr = document.querySelector(".burger");
var seitenbar = document.querySelector(".seitenbar");
let öffnen = false;
burgerr.addEventListener("click", () =>{

    if (öffnen == false) {
        burgerr.classList.add("offen");
        öffnen = true;
       seitenbar.style.left= "0px";
        
    }
   else {
        burgerr.classList.remove("offen");
        öffnen = false;
        seitenbar.style.left="-21vw"
    }
    // if (öffnen==true) {
    //     alert("test")
    // }
}

);



And here is my HTML code of the page that I want to have the burger included
<body>
    <?php
    include "menu.php"    ?>

<link rel=stylesheet href=dashboard.css>

<div id=alles>


    <div id=boxen> 
        <div id=veranstaltungen class=elemente>
            Veranstaltungen
            <!-- Alle Veranstaltungen anzeigen können
            Anzeige, welche Veranstaltungen im Studiengang noch fehlen
            Anzeige, welche Veranstaltungen im Studiengang noch fehlen -->
        </div>
        <div id=veranstaltungen_fertig class=elemente>
        abeschlossene veranstaltungen
        </div>
        <div id=studiengang class=elemente>
        Studiengang
        <!-- Die Noten der Studenten anzeigen lassen, in der Form, dass zu jedem Studiengang jedes Modul angezeigt wird -->
        </div>
    </div>


    
</div>

</body>

and the CSS code of the page

#boxen{
    display:grid;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1vw;
    border-color:black;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: 1vw, 1vw, 1vw;
    justify-content: center;
}

.elemente{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:5vw;
    border-color:cornflowerblue;
}

How to fix this problem?
I already tried it with float:left; but it didn't work and position absolute also didn't really workout

Is there a reason it needs to be implemented in this particular way? Because ul + some CSS works great for either a vertical or horizontal menu, and this seems like it's going to be troublesome to maintain going forward.

no I did it after a tutorial if theres a better way to implement it please tell me. I just wanted to have a menu

Not much to say, just a very basic vanilla navbar with hamburger dropdown. Added some explanatory comments, but I'm no CSS guru so there could be cross-platform issues. Not good with animations, so left that out. Lol.


function toggleDisplay (el, displayAs = 'block') {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(el).display === 'none') {
    el.style.display = displayAs
  } else {
    el.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

const burgerr = document.querySelector('#burgerr')
const seitenbar = document.querySelector('#seitenbar')
const logEl = document.querySelector('#log')

burgerr.addEventListener("click", () => {
  toggleDisplay(seitenbar, 'block')
})

document.querySelector('#menu-close').addEventListener('click', () => {
  toggleDisplay(seitenbar, 'block')
})

document.querySelector('#menu-home').addEventListener('click', () => {
  log.textContent = 'home action'

  toggleDisplay(seitenbar)
})

document.querySelector('#menu-register').addEventListener('click', () => {
  log.textContent = 'register action'

  toggleDisplay(seitenbar)
})

document.querySelector('#menu-login').addEventListener('click', () => {
  log.textContent = 'login action'

  toggleDisplay(seitenbar)
})

document.querySelector('#nav-title').addEventListener('click', () => {
  log.textContent = 'home action'
})
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  user-select: none; /* prevent highlighting menu items */

  #burgerr {
    padding: 0.5rem; /* more fat-finger friendly */
    cursor: pointer; /* interactive cursor */
  }

  > .nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
  }

  #seitenbar {
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    /* remove menu from normal page flow
      so it can't push stuff around.
    */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; /* no positioning drama */
    left: 0; /* just use a close button in menu */
    border: 1px solid gray;

    > li {
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 0.5rem;

      &:not(last-of-type) {
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
      }
    }
  }
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

#log-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <span id="burgerr" title="menu hamburger">&#x2630;</span>

      <h1 id="nav-title">Title | Logo</h1>
    </div>

    <ul id="seitenbar">
      <li id="menu-close">
        <span>Close Menu</span>
      </li>

      <li id="menu-home">
        <span>Home</span>
      </li>

      <li id="menu-register">
        <span>Register</span>
      </li>

      <li id="menu-login">
        <span>Login</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <p>A simple example.</p>

  <div id="log-container">
    <p id="log"></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



